# Test class is not showing any coverage

Tags: apex, unit-test

This is just a simple class but test is not working

```
Public class RefundResult
{
    public String transaction_id;
    public String status;
    public String type;
}
```

I tried using :

```
RefundResult result = new RefundResult();
String transaction_id = '12345';
String status = 'Done!';
String type = 'Test';
```

In test class also used :

```
RefundResult result = new RefundResult();
Result transaction_id = '12345';
Result status = 'Done!';
Result type = 'Test';
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use dot notation to call the member variables of the class.

```
RefundResult result = new RefundResult();
result.transaction_id = '12345';
result.status = 'Done!';
result.type = 'Test';
```

Hope it helps.